# Typescript infer return types from an object of functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have an object

```js
{
  num1: 1,
  num2: 2,
  str: "abc"
}
```

I want to create a function that takes in any of such object as the first input, and a custom selectors object as the second input.

```js
function fn<O extends object, S extends object>(
    obj: O,
    selectors: {
        [K in keyof S]: {
            selector: (obj: O) => InferReturnType;
            equals: (a: InferReturnType, b: InferReturnType) => boolean;
        }
    }
) {
}
```

What I want is to be able to infer the parameters `a`, `b` of the `equals` function to the return type of `selector`.

For example,

```js
fn(
    { num1: 1, num2: 2, str: "abc" },
    {
        selector1: {
            selector: ({ num1, num2 }) => ({ num1, num2 }),
            equals: (a, b) => a.num1 === b.num1 && a.num2 === b.num2,
        },
        selector2: {
            selector: ({ num1, str }) => ({ num1, str }),
            equals: (a, b) => a.num1 === b.num1 && a.str === b.str,
        }
    }
)
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeA8ogpgDylsAEwGdE4AjAKy2gBpEBlbPAksqmqAPgAoAoRIPaUAXInS0BQ4lgA2nOACdiYgN5ShQgNoBpRDCQBrLAE84wRgF01GzXZnzoSsT2JQAhvjHoAlIgC8XIy6lgDctnZCWACOIO6yKog87mIMIfTkqSF+gYjkcHDy7mDhkYIAvraVfuqaAPR1+gC2AA7yTQQesAh8lXwo-JqqiGAgTQCMYuP0o00ATGJz9G6KIgBE7uQQa4jlkkMR0nIKipOItWWaDicuw7PTI2NzuzlBPHdjD7PP5T77l1FYvFEskMq9EO4AHT3AL+fx5aGfRAAMmREMR81h8PIGKWhwqVT4PiAA)

Comment: As far as I know this is currently impossible and there is an open feature request at [ms/TS#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018).  If I were you I'd refactor to something the compiler can handle, possibly like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3v7EN) shows.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXrD1m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: I removed the equals implementation and now hovering on equals infers the correct type. As soon as I add implementation back it becomes unknown. Anyone know why's that? [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeA8ogpgDylsAEwGdE4AjAKy2gBpEBlbPAksqmqAPgAoAoRIPaUAXInS0BQ4lgA2nOACdiYgN5ShQgNoBpRDCQBrLAE84wRgF01GzXZnzoSsT2JQAhvjHoAlIgC8XIy6lgDctnZCWACOIO6yKog87mIMIfTkqSF+gYjkcHDy7mDhkYIAvraVfuqaAPR1+gC2AA7yTQQesAh8lXwo-JqqiGAgTQCMYuP0o00ATGJz9G6KIgBE7uQQa4jlkkMR0nIKipOItWWaDicuw7PTI2NzuzlBPHdjD7PP5T77l1FYvEVIcKlU+D4gA)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! It is indeed a working solution. But it'll be great if selector and its corresponding equality fn can be in the same object.

Comment: @y627chen Even with the implementation it still shows on hover the correct one, however it can't infer the type for the parameters.

Comment: @wonderflame Thanks, it works great! Is there no way we can remove the createSelector wrapper?

Comment: No, unfortunately. should I write the answer explaining?

Comment: y627chen You seem to be missing the point that what you are asking for is currently impossible. Please see [ms/TS#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018).  Until and unless that gets implemented you need to work around it with some sort of refactoring.  I'm happy to write up an answer explaining, although I don't want to bother if you're more inclined to accept a different answer (in which case maybe @wonderflame wants to add the link to the relevant github issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently impossible and there is an open feature request at [ms/TS#53018](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/53018)

Fortunately, there is a possible workaround, but I'm not sure if it is mentioned anywhere. This method requires having a dummy function just to let the compiler infer the type. As you already mentioned, the compiler can see the type of the `equals` field, however, that doesn't infer the type of the argument in the implementation of equal. Thus we can have a separate generic function that would accept a selector and return it back without any changes.

First, let's create a `Selector` type that will accept two optional generic parameters that default to `any`. One for the state's type and the other for the return type of the `selector` function:

```
type Selector<O = unknown, S = unknown> = {
  selector: (state: O) => S;
  equals: (a: S, b: S) => boolean;
};
```

Now, let's apply it in `fn`:

```
function fn<O extends object, S extends Record<string, Selector<O>>>(
  obj: O,
  selectors: S,
) {}
```

Notice that we pass `O` to `Selector`, which is actually the reason why the compiler can propagate the type to the function that we are going to develop.

The dummy function:

```
const createSelector = <O, S>(selector: Selector<O, S>) => selector;
```

Usage:

```
fn(
  { num1: 1, num2: 2, str: 'abc' },
  {
    selector1: createSelector({
      selector: ({ num1, num2 }) => ({ num1, num2 }),
      equals: (a, b) => a.num1 === b.num1 && a.num2 === b.num2,
    }),
  },
);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwD2AnAPAeSgXigEMA7EAGlnyNID4qBvAKCigGcFk10AuKAClbBCwCL2wBKfHRgBuZlAgBHAK6F4rXn0K8YFAEY7JeOntSpEJOQF85jJKmKCoSdBGEQ4iFBio4KMGgEObx5YYK4-WBojOnYvLlsAM2ViFABLByhE4hwFAA8RYgATVihUPQArTn98wpKoACVkDCLMQXQ04gBzf3CMHBpBvnlyirEyeTjODA1YCckmFgB6Jag0gFswRHWIYiFgDOJGK0ZGbOGWeihiZXWARl47ihv1gCZeV4p23gByQj0kD8oFYJpd5CwpiEHs5XO5PNN0HxFiwUZCuJori8ntdbq9gTF+JjbtiXnirOJQSiWEpVOpNIR9ATCAA6LH4PAEPSs4lQABkvKI3Le7M5Qs+4PxlJBjHEciAA)